# Adding Thai calendar

Tags: calendar

Newbie here, enjoying Ubuntu. I often get confused about Thai calendar dates as according to them it is now the year 2065. Any way to get the Thai calendar date, synced with Google calendar, to the top of my screen alongside of the Christian calendar?
Thanks.

Comment: try to look for a gnome shell extension. A quick search didn't find one for me, but possibly you can find one